# MATLAB dir without '.' and '..'

Tags: matlab, dir

the function `dir` returns an array like

```
.
..
Folder1
Folder2
```

and every time I have to get rid of the first 2 items, with methods like :

```
for i=1:numel(folders)
    foldername = folders(i).name;
    if foldername(1) == '.' % do nothing
            continue;
    end
    do_something(foldername)
end
```

and with nested loops it can result in a lot of repeated code.

So can I avoid these "folders" by an easier way?

Thanks for any help!

### Edit:

Lately I have been dealing with this issue more simply, like this :

```
for i=3:numel(folders)
    do_something(folders(i).name)
end
```

simply disregarding the first two items.

**BUT**, pay attention to @Jubobs' answer. Be careful for folder names that start with a nasty character that have a smaller ASCII value than `.`. Then the second method will fail. Also, if it starts with a `.`, then the first method will fail :)

So either make sure you have nice folder names and use one of my simple solutions, or use @Jubobs' solution to make sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## TL; DR

Scroll to the bottom of my answer for a function that lists directory contents except `.` and `..`.

## Detailed answer

The `.` and `..` entries correspond to the current folder and the parent folder, respectively. In *nix shells, you can use commands like `ls -lA` to list everything but `.` and `..`. Sadly, MATLAB's `dir` doesn't offer this functionality.

However, all is not lost. The elements of the output struct array returned by the `dir` function are actually ordered in lexicographical order based on the `name` field. This means that, if your current MATLAB folder contains files/folders that start by any character of ASCII code point smaller than that of the full stop (46, in decimal), then `.` and `..` willl **not** correspond to the first two elements of that struct array.

Here is an illustrative example: if your current MATLAB folder has the following structure (`!hello` and `'world` being either files or folders),

```
.
├── !hello
└── 'world
```

then you get this

```
>> f = dir;
>> for k = 1 : length(f), disp(f(k).name), end
!hello
'world
.
..
```

Why are `.` and `..` not the first two entries, here? Because both the exclamation point and the single quote have smaller code points (33 and 39, in decimal, resp.) than that of the full stop (46, in decimal).

I refer you to this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) for an exhaustive list of the visible characters that have an ASCII code point smaller than that of the full stop; note that not all of them are necessarily legal filename characters, though.

### A custom `dir` function that does not list `.` and `..`

Right after invoking `dir`, you can always get rid of the two offending entries from the struct array before manipulating it. Moreover, for convenience, if you want to save yourself some mental overhead, you can always write a custom `dir` function that does what you want:

```
function listing = dir2(varargin)

if nargin == 0
    name = '.';
elseif nargin == 1
    name = varargin{1};
else
    error('Too many input arguments.')
end

listing = dir(name);

inds = [];
n    = 0;
k    = 1;

while n < 2 && k <= length(listing)
    if any(strcmp(listing(k).name, {'.', '..'}))
        inds(end + 1) = k;
        n = n + 1;
    end
    k = k + 1;
end

listing(inds) = [];
```

#### Test

Assuming the same directory structure as before, you get the following:

```
>> f = dir2;
>> for k = 1 : length(f), disp(f(k).name), end
!hello
'world
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee by documentation that these entries are always the first two?

Comment: @glglgl I don't have a reference for that, but I'll look for one. In my experience, `.` and `..` have always been the first two elements of the struct array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even though it is guaranteed that they are the first 2 elements, I still don't like for loops starting from 3, or ending in numel(x)-2, so I'm looking for a somehow easier way, if possible.

Comment: @Jubobs - From what I've dealt with in `dir`, they seem to always be the first two elements. BTW +1.

Comment: This is definitely true on OS X. In most cases, it would probably be a bad idea to used these other character to prefix a file or folder. However, one place where this could be relevant to Matlab in particular is for packages in objected-oriented programming. The `+` character is used to [prefix package folders](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html#brf3g8k). The decimal value for the `+` character is 43 vs. 46 for `.`.

Comment: `if any(strcmp(listing(k).name, {'.', '..'}))` looks shorter and neater. But it does the same.

Comment: @glglgl You're right; it's much neater. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: downvoted because Trisoloriansunscreen's answer is much better, but this one appears first because it is the accepted answer

Comment: @craq That's your prerogative. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 57):

**A loop-less solution:**

```
d=dir;
d=d(~ismember({d.name},{'.','..'}));
```

Answer (score 3):

a similar solution from the one suggested by Tal is:

```
listing = dir(directoryname);
listing(1:2)=[];   % here you erase these . and .. items from listing
```

It has the advantage to use a very common trick in Matlab, but assumes that you know that the first two items of listing are . and .. (which you do in this case). Whereas the solution provided by Tal (which I did not try though) seems to find the . and .. items even if they are not placed at the first two positions within listing.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: This isn't reliable, because the first two elements of the struct array returned by `dir` are not guaranteed to correspond to `.` and `..`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27337682/2541573).

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using `dir` to get a list of files and and directories, you can use Matlab's [`ls`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html?refresh=true) function instead. On UNIX systems, this just returns the output of the shell's `ls` command, which [may be faster than calling `dir`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17474216/2278029). The `.` and `..` directories won't be displayed (unless your shell is set up to do so). Also, note that the behavior of this function is different between UNIX and Windows systems.

If you still want to use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), and you test each file name explicitly, as in your example, it's a good idea to use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) (or one of its relations) instead of [`==`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) to compare strings. The following would skip all hidden files and folder on UNIX systems:

```
listing = dir;
for i = 1:length(listing)
    if ~strcmp(listing(i).name(1),'.')
        % Do something
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: See my edit. `.` and `..` are not always the first two elements of the struct array.

Comment: @Jubobs: Thank you. That makes sense. I've updated my answer remove potentially code that could cause issues in rare cases (it would probably be fine in 99.99% of cases).

Answer (score 2):

I used: `a = dir(folderPath);`

Then used two short code that return struct:

`my_isdir = a([a.isdir])` Get a struct which only has folder info

`my_notdir = a(~[a.isdir])` Get a struct which only has non-folder info

Answer (score 1):

You may also wanna exclude any other files besides removing dots

```
d = dir('/path/to/parent/folder')
d(1:2)=[]; % removing dots 
d = d([d.isdir])    % [d.isdir] returns a logical array of 1s representing folders and 0s for other entries
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining @jubobs and @Tal solutions:

```
function d = dir2(folderPath)
% DIR2 lists the files in folderPath ignoring the '.' and '..' paths.

if nargin<1; folderPath = '.'; elseif nargin == 1

d = dir(folderPath);
d = d(~ismember({d.name},{'.','..'}));

end
```

Comment: You don't need an error message there if you don't use `varargin`. Let MATLAB generate errors if people try to call the function with too many arguments. Simply do `function d=dir2(name)`. You can test `if nargin<1, name='.'; end`.

Comment: Edited, following Cris' suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above puts together the elements as I see the question having being asked - obtain a list only of directories, while excluding the parents.
Just combining the elements, I would go with:

```
function d = dirsonly(folderPath)
% dirsonly lists the unhidden directories in folderPath ignoring '.' and '..'    
% creating a simple cell array without the rest of the dir struct information

if nargin<1; folderPath = '.'; elseif nargin == 1

d = dir(folderPath);
d = {d([d.isdir] & [~ismember({d.name},{'.','..'})]).name}.';

end
```

if hidden folders in general aren't wanted the ismember line could be replaced with:

```
d = {d([d.isdir] & [~strncmp({d.name},'.',1)]).name}.';
```

if there were very very large numbers of interfering non-directory files it might be more efficient to separate the steps:

```
d = d([d.isdir]);
d = {d([~strncmp({d.name},'.',1)]).name}.';
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the function **startsWith**

```
folders = dir("folderPath");
folders = string({folders.name});
folders = folders(~startsWith(folders,"."))
```

Comment: This would remove all files whose names starts with a dot. In the UNIX world, all hidden files start with a dot. So that could be a useful thing or not depending on the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Potential Solution - just remove the fields

```
Files = dir;
FilesNew = Files(3:end);
```

You can just remove them as they are the first two "files" in the structure

Or if you are actually looking for specific file types:

```
Files = dir('*.mat');
```

Comment: As you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27337682/7328782), the dot and double dot directories are not always the first two entries.

Comment: that is why i put potential