# Format conversion of batch image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

For batch image conversion from jpg to bmp, I workon the following code but it faces with some errors:

```
f=dir('./input')
fil={f.name};
for k=1:numel(fil)
file=fil{k};
new_file=strrep(file,'.jpg','.bmp');
im=imread(file);
imwrite(im,new_file);
end
```

**the errors:**

> Error using imread>get_full_filename (line 513)
>
> Cannot open file "." for reading. You might not have read permission.
>
> Error in imread (line 340)
>
> fullname = get_full_filename(filename);
>
> Error in format_conversion (line 6)
>
> im=imread(file);

Where is the problem?

Comment: The . and .. cause the problem, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337514/matlab-dir-without-and

Comment: @Daniel , The problem still is there even when I use **f=dir('E:\input');**. Moreover, I tried it by removing "." or ".." but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @beaker, Yes, it's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `.` and `..` entries in the folder, and Daniel pointed correctly to a solution in the comments.

However, since you use

```
new_file=strrep(file,'.jpg','.bmp');
```

in your code, it seems that you want to convert files with the extension `.jpg` only (not `.jpeg` or `.JPG` or `.JPEG`). Your code above would also run into problems if there is a `.txt` file or whatever in the directory. Fortunately, MATLAB's `dir` function allows to use wildcards, so the solution might be as easy as:

```
f=dir('./input/*.jpg')
```

Of course, later you will have to add the folder again:

```
im=imread(fullfile('input', file));
imwrite(im,fullfile('input',new_file));
```

A more flexible way than using the fixed  `'input'` is to use `f.folder`, see the [docs of dir](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately, the folowing errors occur:  Error using imread>get_full_filename (line 516)
File "1.jpg" does not exist.           Error in imread (line 340)
    fullname = get_full_filename(filename);

Error in format_conversion (line 6)
    im=imread(file);   ///// But I have 1.jpg in the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution.