# Variable as argument for imread in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, analysis

I am trying to run an image analysis script on ~5,000 files in Matlab. I'm trying to run the main part of the script inside a for loop and iterate across every file name.  I've listed the directory as a a variable and have come up with something like the following:

```
images = dir
images.name
imagesdim = size(images)
imageslength = imagesdim(1)

for i = 1:imageslength
    cimg =  imread(images(i,1).name);
    etc etc
end
```

However, this doesn't seem to be an acceptable input argument for imread.  Is there any way I can format this list so that I can use a variable here, or will I have to copy this argument 5,000 times?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message you get, it will help us understand what is going on.

Comment: Maybe this is your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337514/matlab-dir-without-and

Answer (score 0):

I do this in directories of images using the function form of the [dir](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) command. For example, if you are working with TIFF files:

```
dir_items = dir('*.tiff');
file_names = {dir_items.name};
disp('Using .tiff files found in current directory:')
disp(file_names');
for k = 1:length(file_names)
    disp(file_names{k})
    cimg = imread(file_names{k});
end
```

If you can't use the wildcard filter like "*.tiff", then you have to check the isdir field of each struct in the array, like so:

```
dir_items = dir;
for k = 1:length(dir_items)
    if dir_items(k).isdir==1
        fprintf(1,'%s is a directory (ignore)\n',dir_items(k).name)
    else
        disp(dir_items(k).name)
        cimg = imread(dir_items(k).name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way of iterating through a folder, or nested folder of images in MATLAB is to use imageDatastore.

```
imds = imageDatastore(desiredDirectory,"FileExtensions",[".tif",".tiff"]);

while hasdata(imds)
     img = read(imds);
     % Your code that operates on img
end
```